# How to explain the advantage of Schmitt trigger over comparator for pulse conditioning?

Tags: schmitt-trigger

[image]

Above is the unshaped input pulse train. Red line is the set point for the comparator.

I see many pulse conditioning and sharpening circuits use Schmitt triggers instead of comparators.

Imagine the input pulse train is not sharp enough so we need to make it sharper. There are some applications in industry where you need sharp pulses to count frequencies. My question is:

Why not only to use a comparator? Is that because rising and falling edges are sharper in case of Schmitt trigger? Could one explain it in an illustrative manner?

Comment: very rarely will you find a comparator without positive feedback, thus you are using a schmitt trigger. And the advantage of a schmitt trigger over a non-positive feedback comparator is to eliminate multiple edges at point of threshold crossing.

Comment: Noise rejection is the name of what @JonRB said..

Comment: As a generalization, popcorn Schmitt trigger logic (few to tens of nS) tends to be several orders of magnitude faster (lower tpd) than a comparator (few to tens of uS).  I'm not certain of why this is, but would venture that it is process related.  As stated above, hysteresis can be easily added to a comparator making it roughly equivalent.

Comment: i cannot illustrate your words in my mind. if the input is a pulse train with long rise and fall times or it is not sharp enough, why wouldnt a comparator be worse than a Schmitt trigger case. can you explain it in a  more plain language or illustrate?

Comment: Imagine the signal is somewhat noisy (it is always the case). Then there will be a little ripple around the crossing point. It will cause the output of comparator change it's value back and forth around that point. By adding some hysteresis to the comparator (turning it into Schmitt trigger) you are avoiding this problem. Kind of debouncing analogy.

Comment: Eugene I dont understand I edited my question with my drawing. This kind of input signal Im talking about and the red line is the set point by the "comparator". Why would there be still possibility for false swings?

Comment: do you think there still will be an issue when the signal is crossing the red set point? Why?

Comment: Yo will *never* get a perfectly smooth signal, so you can't (usually) assume monotonically rising/falling line near the crossing points.

Comment: im trying to understand. do you mean if i zoom into the crossing point there will be ripples there in the neighborhood of the intersection of the red line and the signal?

Comment: Yes, that's the thing

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.slideshare.net/saquib208/schmitt-trigger-basics). Slide 13 has the illustration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're feeding a digital input, a Schmidt trigger is preferable in most cases because it will clean up the signal and match your logic levels. It will also help avoid meta-stablity (ie when the voltage level is right in the middle of on and off, its bad).
A comparator could possibly give you metastable values if the amplifier is fast enough and if your digital input is clocked really fast or an interrupt.
It also depends because a comparator has only one voltage value and a schmidt trigger has two points when it transistions[image]

Comment: when would you prefer a comparator to a Schmitt trigger? can u give an application example?

Comment: Depending on the input signal if it was beyond the rails of my digital vcc it may be advantageous to switch to a comparator. Comparators have a different input structure with generally higher impedance instead of gates on a schmitt trigger. It depends on how they are built, you can actually make a comparator behave like a schmitt trigger but you have to add external components.

Comment: but im already telling you the spesific input

Comment: I don't see any specific voltage level on that graph, is it 50V is it 3V? What do you want the output to be? Do you have any timing requirements?